# DNN Account Registration Module

Tags: dotnetnuke

How do I add custom fields to the Account Registration module in DNN 7? Are they stored in the  element in the web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add these as Custom Profile properties in the DNN user profile area.

Check out this DNN 6.2 video for how to customize registration, the look is a little different in 7, but the functionality is the same.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/443/View/Details/Customizing-user-registration-within-DotNetNuke-6-2.aspx